# Interact with Each Iteration of itertools.product

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I'm using the `product` method from the `itertools` python library to calculate all permutations of items in a list of lists. As an example:

```
>> elems = [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]
>> permutations = list(itertools.product(*elems))
>> print permutations
# this prints [(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```

How can I check each permutation as it is calculated, rather than returning the entire set of permutations at once? The problem I am currently facing is that I run into a python `Memory Error` while running my script because too many permutations are being generated. I only care about a single one of the permutations. If I can check each permutation as it is generated, I can store just a single value rather than storing every possible permutation. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it in a for loop, one at a time:

```
for a_perm in itertools.product(*elems):
    print(a_perm)
```

`itertools.product()` gives you iterator, which you can iterate over one item at a time.

Comment: Say you want to sum the elements in each permutation, you could also process this in a generator: `(sum(a_perm) for a_perm in itertools.product(*elems))`. I like to think of this as popping an item from a queue, applying an operating to the item, and pushing the result into another queue, and it'll still work even if the queues are nearly infinite or infinite in length.